# How to send data from model to controller node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, model-view-controller, es6-promise, connection-pooling

I am calling getIndex function in contoller from routes and fetchAll from model is getting data from database but how to store the data and send it to contoller and how to receive in contoller.

**This is how i have connected the database**

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const pool = mysql.createPool({
host: 'localhost',
user: 'root',
database: 'practice',
password: ''
});
module.exports = pool.promise();
```

**model**

```
const db = require('../database');

module.exports = class User {   
fetchAll(){
     db.execute('SELECT * FROM users')
     .then(([rows,fieldData]) => {
         console.log(rows); //giving the required data
      })
}
}
```

**controller**

```
const User = require('../model/user');

exports.getIndex = (req,res,next) => {
const user = new User();
user.fetchAll();
res.render('index');
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a good example of where to use promises and async/await

in modal do this

```js
const db = require('../database');

module.exports = class User {
    fetchAll() {
        return (new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            db.execute('SELECT * FROM users')
                .then(([rows, fieldData]) => {
                    resolve(rows); // return data
                })
        }))

    }
}
```

in the controller do this

```js
const User = require('../model/user');

exports.getIndex = async (req, res, next) => {
    const user = new User();
    let data = await user.fetchAll();
    res.render('index');
};
```